# After upgrading to the NPSP 3, can I safely delete all "Households"?

Tags: delete, nonprofit-starter-pack, households

[image: Storage Usage]

I recently upgraded my organization to the Nonprofit Starter Pack 3 and switched over to the Household Account model (from the 1-to-1 model).

I have already deleted all the deprecated 1-to-1 accounts.

Am I also safe to delete all "Households" (npo02__household__c) now that households are done through the Account object? Is there any documentation on doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Once you have converted to the Household Account model and confirmed that everything has been successfully migrated, you don't need the data in the Household custom object anymore. Feel free to delete to save storage space.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think you'd be "safe", but I'd recommend you ask in the "Upgrading to NPSP3 Group" in the [The Power of Us Hub](http://www.salesforce.org/power-of-us-hub) as that's where you'd get the definitive answer. The [Nonprofit Starter Pack 3 Upgrade Guide](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/Upgrade-to-NPSP3-from-a-Previous-Version-of-NPSP) doesn't address it. If you choose to do it without checking, be sure to export all the data in CSV format to back it up first.